# Why can't the template argument be deduced?

Tags: c++, math, boost, odeint

I use odeint from the boost library and as a beginner in C++ do not understand the issue at hand. Given the following source code within a file called ODESystem.hpp

```
#include "blaze/Math.h"
class ODESystem {
    public:
        using Complex = std::complex< Float >;
        using StateVector = blaze::DynamicVector< Complex,
                                                  blaze::columnVector >;


        void operator()(const StateVector &x, StateVector &dxdt, const double t);
};

void ODESystem::operator()(const ODESystem::StateVector &x, ODESystem::StateVector &dxdt, const double t) {
        // don't do anything here.
    }
```

as well as a simple call in main.cpp to odeint via

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ODESystem::StateVector h( 3UL, 7.0F );
    // ODESystem sys is properly initialized beforehand
    boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(sys, h,0.,10.,.1);
}
```

I cannot see why the compiler tells me

> /usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate.hpp(53): note: this candidate was rejected because at least one template argument could not be deduced
>     integrate( System system , State &start_state , Time start_time , Time end_time , Time dt , Observer observer )

From what I have read here in similar posts it has to be connected to non-deducible context but I simply do not know enough to see where it applies here.

Comment: Impossible to answer without MCVE.

Comment: Well in fact I thought this to be a MCVE. Am I wrong? Just include blaze and boost into the source code and compile it. Then the error should show up. I might be wrong. If yes, please narrow what is needed further.

Comment: An MCVE is something which can be copied from your example and pasted into  editor and than compiled.

Comment: I might miss something but I think it should work now as long as blaze and boost are available on the system

Answer (score 0):

With certain changes this compiles fine

```
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

class ODESystem {
public:
    using Complex =  float ;
    using StateVector = std::vector<Complex>;
    void operator()(const StateVector &x, StateVector &dxdt, const double t)
    {}
};
bool operator>(const std::complex< float > & f, const std::complex< float > & d)
{
    return false;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ODESystem sys;
    ODESystem::StateVector h(3UL, 7.0F);
    // ODESystem sys is properly initialized beforehand
    boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(sys, h, 0., 10., .1);
}
```

just changing to

```
using Complex =  std::complex<float> ;
```

and you get into trouble because you will have to refine operator> for complex and pow...

As for your compilation error have you forgot any blaze header ?